# ERC20 Token buy

Tags: testing, blockchain, solidity, ethers.js, erc20

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Erc20 smart contract testing", function () {
  let token;
  let accounts;
  const amount = ethers.parseEther("1"); 

  before(async function () {
    const referencetToABI = await ethers.getContractFactory("BikashToken");
    token = await referencetToABI.deploy();
    accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
  });


  it("Buying token Successful", async function () {
    const buyer = accounts[2];
    const tokenAmount = amount.mul(1000);// Using 1 Ether buying 1000 Token

    await token.connect(buyer).buy({ value: amount });

    expect(await token.balanceOf(buyer.address)).to.equal(tokenAmount);
  });
});
```

I am testing a ERC20 solidity smart contract. But this code gives me an error =  TypeError: amount.mul is not a function
how can I fix this ? I was wathing a youtube video, there `amount.mul()` function works properly, but in my machine it is showing error. Please help.

**buy() function in contrats:**

```
function buy() public payable returns (bool) {
        require(
            msg.sender.balance >= msg.value && msg.value != 0 ether,
            "ICO: function buy invalid input"
        );
        uint256 amount = msg.value * 1000;
        _transfer(owner(), _msgSender(), amount);
        return true;
}
```

Comment: What solidity version are you using?

Comment: you probably need to import math and apply a using